# How to handle a complex set of nested for loops vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, iteration

So I'm struggling to wrap my head around something I'm trying to write. Nest for-next loops are clearly the only way to go (as far as I can tell) but I just can't get any sort of pseudo code worked out. My problem is this, given a fixed number (lets say 100 for simplicity) I want to iterate through all combinations of sets of numbers upto 5 that totals 100. Lets say in steps of 5. So to be clear I would want to run the following first few example:

```
100
95 - 5
90 - 10
---
10 - 90
5 - 95
90 - 5 - 5
85 - 5 - 10
80 - 5 - 15
---
5 - 5 - 85
85 - 10 - 5
80 - 10 - 10
75 - 10 - 15
---
---
80 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 5
75 - 5 - 5 - 5 - 10
---
```

Hopefully that give you the idea of my my target is. My problem is that I just can't work out an effective way to program. I'm pretty competent in actually writing code (usually) but every time I sit down and do this I end up with 10's of nested for-next loops that just don't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove that nesting problem there's a simple approach : use a [queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
// add 1 item to start with in the queue

while(queue.Count > 0)
{
    // 1. dequeue item from queue
    // 2. do your work on it
    // 3. if there's another combination emerging from step 2, enqueue it in the queue
}

// 4. this point will be reached once finished
```

Using a custom type to store whatever information you need for that job and by having a single loop instead of many should help you tackle the problem relatively quickly :D